# Error while running mongod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I installed mongodb using this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

When I run mongod, I get this:

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6265 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 32-bit host=aboelseoud
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] 
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] **       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] **       with --journal, the limit is lower
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] 
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.3, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] git version: f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] build info: Linux bs-linux32.10gen.cc 2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Feb 15 12:39:36 EST 2008 i686 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] options: {}
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 dbexit: 
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Fri Mar  1 18:11:06 dbexit: really exiting now
```

When I type mongo, I get this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: test
Fri Mar  1 18:13:00 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91
exception: connect failed
```

When I browse into localhost:3000, I get this:

```
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure in MembersController#lawlab

Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: MongoDB will not create the `/data/db` folder for you, you must do that bit, however, if you installed from repo the mongod will already be running from another location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should create data/db/ folder and give access to your user to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity sake: there is a difference between creating data/db folder vs. /data/db. One is installed in the root, one is not. So, you should create /data/db/ folder and then give access to the folder by using sudo chown -R  /data/db/